# How to apply Materials "Responsive layout grid" to Android Compose?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to align my components based on the Material responsive layout grid, as visualized by [image: this picture] from https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#columns-gutters-and-margins.

I don't necessarily want my content to be included in a column but rather put baselines on either a start or an end of a column.

A simple example:

```kotlin
// FIXME: What to do? 
@Composable
fun example() {
    Button(onClick = { 
        }, text = "Stretch me between start of column 2 and end of column 4"
    )
}
```

My best guess is that I need to use this library somehow: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary
But I'm still clueless...

How can I achieve what I want to do in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is not clear. Please comment if this is not what you are looking for.

To have a button with a width of 2 columns in a 4 column grid system. You can use `weight` and `Spacer` to achieve the requirement.

This starts at starting of Column 2 and ends at the ending of Column 3.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Button(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(2f),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Center Button")
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Using `weight` and `padding` modifiers, along with `Spacer` we can achieve most of the grid requirements.

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted to do, even though it is a bit disappointing. 

I still need to add the gutter sizes and it doesn't deal with the breakpoints, as discussed here: https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#breakpoints, but that is beyond the scope of my question.

I would expect an API from the Material library which incorporates all these concepts somehow. But your example solves the problem.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps!